# What is the equivalent of this form of choice?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

Add a primitive one place predicate symbol $\mathcal Df$, signifying "is parameter free definable", to the language of $\sf ZF$, and add the following:

**Axiom scheme of definability:** If $\varphi(Y)$ is a formula that doesn't use the symbol $``\mathcal Df"$, in which only the symbol $``Y"$ occur free, and never occur as bound, then:$$\forall X [\forall Y (Y \in X \leftrightarrow \varphi(Y)) \to \mathcal Df(X)]$$; is an axiom.

**Axiom of definable choice:**

$\forall X [\emptyset \not \in X \to \\\exists F (F:X \to \bigcup(X) \land \forall x \in X(\mathcal Df(x) \to F(x) \in x))]$

In English: For any family of non empty *definable* sets there is a function that sends each set in it to an element of that set.

> Question: Now to which of the known forms of axiom of choice this would be equivalent?
>
> IF not equivalent to any, then would it entail existence of non-measurable sets as $AC$ does.

Where by equivalent it is meant some choice statement $\varphi$ in the pure language of set theory [i.e.; doesn't use the symbol $\mathcal Df$] that is provable here, and such that on the other hand "$\sf ZF$ + Definability + $\varphi$" would prove definable choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent" here? Are you asking about equiconsistency between your theory and some theory $ZF + \varphi$ where $\varphi$ is a choice axiom?

Comment: (Also, I think you want to restrict to non-empty definable $x$ in the statement of the axiom of definable choice.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the non-empty definable $x$ issue. Equivalent is not 'equi-consistency' here, because its clear that this would be equi-consistent with ZFC over a point free model of it. No it means some choice statement $\varphi$ in the pure language of set theory that is provable here, and such that on the other hand ZF + definability + $\varphi$ would prove definable choice.

Comment: You need to require that $\varphi$ does not mention $\cal Df$, otherwise you can define the least ordinal which is not in $\cal Df$, which means the whole class of ordinals is pointwise definable, and therefore the power set of each ordinal is definable without parameters, and so is the second power set. And then definable choice implies choice, since it implies the power set of an ordinal can be well-ordered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, $\mathcal Df$ is not a symbol of the pure language of set theory, and I've already restricted $\varphi$ to that language.

Comment: I don't see where you claim to have made that restriction...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, OK thanks, I thought you meant my comment. I see that you mean the definability scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language of set theory, and let $\mathcal{L'}$ be the extended language with $\mathcal{Df}$. Let's write $\text{Def}$ for the definability schema, and $\text{DefC}$ for definable choice. You're looking for an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ which is equivalent to $\text{DefC}$ over $\mathsf{ZF} + \text{Def}$.

I claim that if an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZF} + \text{Def} + \varphi\vdash \text{DefC}$, then already $\mathsf{ZF} + \varphi \vdash \text{AC}$.

To see this, let $M$ be any model of $\mathsf{ZF} + \varphi$. Then we can expand $M$ to an $\mathcal{L}'$-structure $M'\models \mathsf{ZF} + \text{Def} + \varphi$ by interpreting $\mathcal{Df}$ to hold of every set (note that $\text{Def}$ only says that certain sets satisfy $\mathcal{Df}$, it doesn't require that any sets fail to satisfy $\mathcal{Df}$). Thus $M'\models \text{DefC}$. But since $\mathcal{Df}$ holds of every set in $M'$, this implies that $M\models \text{AC}$. So by the completeness thoerem, $\mathsf{ZF} + \varphi \vdash \text{AC}$.

It follows that if $\varphi$ is equivalent to $\text{DefC}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}+\text{Def}$, then $\mathsf{ZF}+\text{Def}+\text{DefC}\vdash \varphi$, and since $\mathsf{ZF}+\varphi\vdash \text{AC}$, we have $\mathsf{ZF}+\text{Def}+\text{DefC}\vdash \text{AC}$. I don't believe the latter conclusion (since there should be a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ which satisfies choice for all parameter-free definable sets but not all sets), so I would conclude that $\text{DefC}$ is not equivalent to any $\mathcal{L}$-sentence over $\mathsf{ZF}+\text{Def}$.

Comment: although this is another question really, but what happens if an omega rule is added to ensure that $Df$ is about only parameter free definable sets, like in saying that: If all instances of the following schema  are true $\forall x [\forall y (y \in x \iff \pi_i) \to \phi(x)]$ where $\pi_1, \pi_2,....$ are *ALL* parameter free formulas in the $\mathcal L$ , i.e. only have $y$ free in them, then we infer $\forall x (\phi(x))$. Would that change the conclusion above.

Comment: left is the answer to the second question, about non-measurable sets?